# Add a column based on values present in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as:

| id | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Auto |
| 1 | Manual |
| 2 | Auto |
| 3 | Manual |
| 4 | Manual |

I want to add another column based on values present in second column as:

| id | Value | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Auto | Yes |
| 1 | Manual |  |
| 2 | auto | Yes |
| 3 | manual |  |
| 4 | Manual |  |

I tried below code:

```py
mask = df['Purchase Order Num'].str.contains('Auto', na= False, case=False)
df['Flag'] = np.where(df[mask], 'Yes', '')
```

I get the error as :

> Length of values (2) does not match length of index (5)

What went wrong?

Comment: `np.where(mask, 'Yes', '')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we doing the `np.where` we need pass the whole Boolean to it

```
mask = df['Purchase Order Num'].str.contains('Auto', na= False, case=False)
df['Flag'] = np.where(mask, 'Yes', '')
```

pandas assign can do

```
df['Flag'] = ''
df.loc[mask, 'Flag'] = 'Yes'
```